# Matching numerical dataset to closest set in library

Tags: correlation, matching

I have numerical, 1D datasets from measurements that I each want to match to the closest dataset in a library containing similar datasets. Coding is done in Matlab. Unfortunately I am not too experienced with this kind of work (this is for my mech. eng. master thesis) and I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I have included a figure of what one of the better dataset looks like. This data represents cepstra which I will use to perform ranging using a hydrophone.

[image: Typical dataset]

[image: Cepstrogram]

There is a bit of noise but the relevant pieces are the negative peaks flanked by positive peaks, and the large positive peak in the second half of the dataset is significant as well. The horizontal position of these peaks changes throughout the datasets, as does the amplitude. The horizontal position is the most significant in this specific case.

For now I have tried matching with Pierson, a variant of euclidean distance and cross correlation with varying degrees of success. Interestingly enough the Pierson method seems to work best, but as this is hardly a linear dataset I assume there must be better methods.

It would actually be best to have a robust method to find the exact horizontal position of the negative and positive peaks and match this to library datasets with similar horizontal positions, but as there is so much noise in most of the datasets (both measurements and library, as the library is made of measurements) I could not get peak finding algorithms to work. The dataset I posted is one of the better ones, some of them just look like its all noise as the amplitude of the relevant peaks decreases.

Which algorithm or method could you advise me to use for this problem? Or could you point me in the right direction to find a suitable algorithm?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jan.  I believe there are too many possible solutions to make this answerablew, because an appropriate approach depends on what these measurements mean, on their statistical characteristics (such as the autocovariance structure), what you mean by "peak," and what you mean by "similar."  To what extent can you supply this essential information?

Comment: @whuber thank you for your reply. There are no statistical characteristics, these datasets are actually ceptra made from sound measurements for sonar purposes. The (negative) peaks that I mean are the parts with the highest amplitudes at 0.0045 and 0.006 approximately. I used other cepstra for which an essential parameter is known to generate a library, and now I want to use this library to estimate this essential parameter for other cepstra

Comment: Spectra (and derived quantities like cepstra) definitely have statistical characteristics!  Indeed, to my eye what you have posted can be more than adequately described as white noise and none of the peaks can be distinguished from the average.  It's absolutely essential to give enough information to characterize what's in the library and to be able to determine when an apparent signal (or match) is real instead of the result of random fluctuations.

Comment: @whuber I have included a ceptrogram which represents an older version of my library. When put together in a cepstrogram the objective becomes clearer I hope. At least the trend and the peaks that I mean are more recognisable. The idea is to find the dataset/cepstrum in this cepstrogram that is most similar to a cepstrum generated by a measurement so I can infer the range to the source from it